# How to manipulate the request url for chunk js file inside require.ensure callback of webpack?

Tags: express, lazy-loading, webpack, require, react-router

As web development goes on, the js bundle file grows bigger and bigger, which brings forth great latency of the initial rendering of the webpage. I am studying webpack recently, and inside it uses **require.ensure** to do the lazy loading, which is so amazing. But I encounter an issue for my specific scenario.

It is described as below:
When I bundle my js files, it will generate two chunks:
`./bundle/bundle.js
 ./bundle/1.js (which is for lazy lodaing)`

However, I want to lazy load **1.js** in different pages. But the request for it are different on different pages.

Eg. If on page1, it is requesting http://localhost/page1/1.js.
While on page2, it is requesting http://localhost/page2/1.js.

This poses a problem for backend that it does not know how to serve the file to it. So really wonder how could it be solved? Is there a way to manipulate the request url in require.ensure callback function so that wherever page it is, it is requesting using same url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use [publicPath](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/configuration#outputpublicpath) parameter in your webpack config - it is exactly what you want:

```
output: {
    ...
    publicPath: '/scripts/' // Path to scripts relative to your site root
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Just tried it, works! And the path must be absolute path, which starts with ''/", not "./".